# mod rewrite - multiply pages, same prefix

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am currently using this mod_rewrite via .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forum$ /forum.php [L]  
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]*)$ /viewforum.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/t([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ /viewtopic.php?cid=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

The first three rules works. The urls are like this:

- http://domain.com/forum - forum.php
- http://domain.com/forum/ -forum.php
- http://domain.com/forum/71 - viewforum.php?id=71

The problem lies with the last rule; the viewtopic rule. When I go to this URL:

http://domain.com/forum/t71-129, which should be: `viewtopic.php?cid=71&id=129` although, when I enter the rewritten url, it shows viewtopic.php

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forum$ /forum.php [L]  
RewriteRule ^forum/([0-9]*)$ /viewforum.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/t([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)$ /viewtopic.php?cid=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

An enhancement for Catalins solution. With this path it also works for redirecting /forum/ to forum.php :

```
RewriteRule ^forum/?$ /forum.php [L]
```

Another way could be this:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([0-9]+)$ /viewforum.php?id=$1 [L]
```